# My Internal HDD Backup Drive Not Recognized after new Windows install

Tags: hard-drive, system-restore

I have been backing up files to an second HDD internal to my laptop, including system image backups.  We will call this the D drive.

Today my main SSD with Windows failed, so I went and bought a new SSD and re installed Windows - however I cannot access any of the files on the D drive.  It says the the D drive needs to be formatted.  So - I would love to be able to restore my new C drive from the image on the D drive.  Why doesn't Windows recognize the D drive (that was working fine prior to the SSD failing).

Again, the specific error is:
You need to format the disk before you can use it.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for fun:

Dismiss the error. Open a command prompt and type:

```
chkdsk d: /f
```

Comment: It says "The type of the file system is RAW. CHKDSK is not available for RAW Drives"

Comment: The filesystem on drive d: is damaged. It has lost its file structure, but the files are still there. There are a number of utils that can help, but it's not for the faint of heart! See this link: http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/format-recovery-software/chkdsk-not-available-raw-drive.htm. If you manage to recover everything I would seriously consider replacing the drive and copying its contents to the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Drive was actually encrypted by a 3rd party software ... which I failed to realize until I got a new drive and re-installed everything :(

Me: 0